# Multiple arguments in one function/method

Tags: java

How can I make this work? I need to implement this interface in Rectangular class and a few other classes. The thing is that one class needs to use this method with one value, the other with two and so on. When overriding the method in the class I get the error: cannot be resolved to a type

```java
interface CalculateArea
{
    public int Calculate(int... values); 
}

class Rectangular implements CalculateArea
{
    int width;
    int hight;
    int Area;
    public Rectangular()
    {
        System.out.println("No arguments given");
    }
    public Rectangular(int width, int hight)
    {
        this.width=width;
        this.hight=hight;
        Area = Calculate(width, hight);
    }
    @Override
    public int Calculate(int width, int hight) 
    {
        return (width * width);
    }
```

Comment: you mean a variable amount of argument ? not "many"

Comment: I mean something like an array of objects

Comment: So use an array as parameter, what's the problem ?

Comment: overriding a method need to have the same signature, and the parameters ARE part of the signature. The children class can only the vargs given has 2 values

Comment: Also regarding your code, the method Calculate DOES not need any parameter because it uses only attributs of the class, you don't need to pass them

Comment: I see now. Such a stupid mistake. Sorry for the question.